# Inject variable values into Katex/Latex syntax

Tags: reactjs, variables, math, input, katex

I am working on a project that uses **Katex** format to display mathematical formulas.

Now I am facing a bit of a problem here.

For rendering a fraction the katex syntax is

```
    \dfrac{x}{y}
```

Now if I have a variable **x** of value **3** and another variable **y** of value **5**.

How would I inject the values into the *Katex* syntax?

I want to have something like

```
var x = 3;
var y = 5;

\dfrac{x}{y}
```

where the *x* and *y* in *katex syntax* will be replaced by the actual values.

Note: I am also using the https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-katex

to render Katex.

Comment: [String.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)?

Comment: what in this case `\dfrac{a}{c}` and I have variables **a** and **c**? @NicoSchertler

Comment: What about this case? You must have a set of variables and you do the replacement for all of them.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd use [macro substitution](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/master/README.md#rendering-options) for this. Try to get your formula expressed as `\frac{\x}{\y}` by whatever machinery is generating the formula. Then you can substitute either the variable names or the values in place of those macros. Something like this:

```
katex.render("\\frac{\\x}{\\y}", element, {
  macros: {
    "\\x": String(x),
    "\\y": String(y),
  }
});
```

If you don't have a way to control how the formulas are constructed initially, this merely shifts the problem from substituting values into the formula to substituting commands into it. In that case, you probably want to tokenize the input string into [commands `\…`](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/9e6eb3a2196901eedbec7031484f2ae927c88367/src/Lexer.js#L37) and other letters. Commands remain as they are, while other letters are subject to variable substitution.

One thing to be careful of is grouping: Input `\frac xy` renders just fine, but with `x=34.5` and `y=5.67` substituted in the naive way, the result `\frac 34.55.67` (which is what both text and macro substitution will give you) renders as `\frac{3}{4}.55.67`. So make sure that each macro you have in your formula is enclosed by `{…}` or add another level of `{…}` when you do the substitution as in `"\\x": "{" + x + "}"`. Enclosing macros by `{…}` inside the formula has the benefit that you won't have to worry about a macro eating a subsequent space: `\text{\x is 2}` is bad but `\text{{\x} is 2}` is better.

But even with grouping done correctly, this approach is not perfect since not all non-commands are indeed variables. For example with `\begin{array}{rlrl}…\end{array}` neither the `a` in `array` nor the `r` in `rlrl` should be considered a variable. Fixing this is really problematic, as it requires a lot of semantic insight.

One way to tackle this dilemma would be letting KaTeX do its rendering and then doing the substitution in the resulting DOM subtree. You should be able to identify variables as `<span class="mord …">…</span>` (`mord` stands for math ordinary). This means you depend on the exact representation KaTeX uses for its output, so you should make sure you run a fixed version of KaTeX as these internal things are subject to change without notice. Also be aware of the fact that in some (possibly future) version this might break certain constructs which depend on the width of a given box, although even things as problematic as `\underbrace` appear to work with this substitution approach at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, @MvG for your insight. I did not know about the _macros_ thing... Thanks for that.. by the way... I was already using JavaScript string interpolation method provided by katex... You can find that in the bottom of the docs... It is working fine for small formulas but larger equation ... It turns into hell ... And also I have to substitute variable values from more than one source.